Pine Script: strategy.exit Error with Trailing Stop and Stop Loss
I'm working on a Pine Script strategy for TradingView, and I'm encountering an error with my strategy.exit function. The error message is:
Here's the relevant portion of my code:
// Execute trades based on the buy conditions for long and short positions
if startLongTrade
    strategy.entry("Buy Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit Long", from_entry="Buy Long", limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfitPercent), stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLossPercent))
    strategy.exit("Trailing Stop Long", from_entry="Buy Long", trail_offset=strategy.position_avg_price * trailingStopPercent)

The issue is on the line with strategy.exit("Trailing Stop Long", from_entry="Buy Long", trail_offset=strategy.position_avg_price * trailingStopPercent).
My intention is to implement both a take profit and a trailing stop. How can I properly set up my strategy.exit calls to resolve this error and achieve the desired functionality?

What's the error message?


Do not make two exits from one entry, if you do not plan to partially close positions, only the exit that comes first in the code will work, combine your exit into one.
If you want to see different comments in the captions under the arrows on the chart for different reasons for exits, use the appropriate comment_* argument, for example comment_trailing for a caption for an exit by trailing or comment_loss for a caption for an exit based on a stop loss
In the last line from your example you have an incomplete function call; you need to define at least one loss, profit, limit, stop or a pair of trailings. trail_offset sets the exit level for a trailing order, but for it to work, you need to determine the activation level through the trail_points or trail_price argument

